# Cannnot Run Mediapipe App Executable With Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, mediapipe

I am not able to run an executable file I have made of an app using mediapipe from Pyinstaller. I get this error when I run the executable file:

[image: Error on terminal window]

I have bundled the mediapipe files with the app in the .spec folder using the datas property:

```
`


   block_cipher = None



   a = Analysis(
       ['PycharmProjects\\EyeblinkDetect\\Blink_Communicate\\app_interface.py'],
        pathex=[],
        binaries=[],
        datas=[('C:\\Users\\grace\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\mediapipe\\python\\solutions\\face_mesh.py', 'mediapipe\\python\\solutions'),  ('C:\\Users\\grace\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-                                          packages\\mediapipe\\python\\solution_base.py', 'mediapipe\\python')],
        hiddenimports=[],
        hookspath=[],
        hooksconfig={},
        runtime_hooks=[],
        excludes=[],
        win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
        win_private_assemblies=False,
        cipher=block_cipher,
        noarchive=False,
    )


    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,cipher=block_cipher) 

    exe = EXE(pyz, Tree('PycharmProjects\\EyeblinkDetect\\Blink_Communicate\\'),
         a.scripts,
         a.binaries,
         a.zipfiles,
         a.datas,
         *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins + gstreamer.dep_bins)],
         upx=True,
         name='BlinkCommunicate')`
```